# Is this function $f$ onto for all positive integers?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Is this function $f$ onto for all positive integers?

$f(x) = x+2$

$\Bbb Z^+ \to\Bbb Z^+$

what about $1$?

Comment: You are very near the solution already. What is it that's troubling you about $f(x) = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a $x\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $f(x)=1$, then this implies $x+2=1,$ i.e.  $x=-1\not\in\mathbb{Z^+}$; so this is a contradiction. Hence $1$ has no preimage in $\mathbb{Z^+}$, which says that the function is not onto.